I want to answer a closed question
Why this has been closed at all?
Are there different types of randomness?
I want to answer pointing out the existence of the theories dealing with uncertain probabilities such as possibility theory and evidence theory, which extend the probability theory and their implications towards the free will argument.
P.S. Reopened, thanks.

You should make the PS an answer. And accept it
